# Does minifying HTML have an impact on SEO?

Tags: seo, html

What happens when I minify my HTML in SEO terms? I mean, I minified my HTML which means that every `<meta... />` tag is being placed on one line.

Will this affect my SEO at all?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Only in the sense that your page will download faster and Google gives you points for that because a faster page load is a better user experience. Otherwise, minimizing your page has no other impact.

Comment: Google reads web pages by tag order, not by line endings or whitespace position, so a properly formatted html stream will read the same whether it is minified or not. Just faster when minified as there's less data. The only time it makes a difference is if Javascript comes unglued because certain formatting was ignored. If you are the type who follows C style programming conventions, this usually isn't an issue, if you're using the "leave just about everything out possible" Basic style program formatting, interesting things happen during minification.

Comment: If you really want faster loading speeds, one would remove bloat from their webpage (remember when pages were less than a megabyte?) and use compression

Comment: @ColeJohnson how do you compress a HTML document?? :/

Comment: You need to configure the webserver to use something like gzip when serving the pages. It will do the compression for you.

Comment: @MartinUeding thanks! does this actually effect load speeds??

Comment: @RahulBasu: I assume it affects the load speeds since text can be compressed a lot. See [Codinghorror post](https://blog.codinghorror.com/http-compression-and-iis-6-0/). If your clients use broadband then the latency is becoming more of a problem. Then combining assests like JavaScript and CSS into less files (less requests, less roundtrips) will give you the greater speed improvement.

Comment: It should be noted that speed is a minor factor in SEO. And once you're using gzip, minifying on top of that makes very little difference.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat Depends on what you consider minor and how that conflicts with what Google thinks about that: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/?hl=en

Comment: @Rob Not sure what you mean about conflict. Google providing a tool has no relevance to how large a factor it is in SERPs. They have stated on numerous occasions that it's a minor signal.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat If you read any of the documentation and videos Google has released over the years, you'll find Google emphasizing, over and over, the importance of page loading and user experience. Two competing web sites with the exact same content, the one with the better user experience will rank higher every time. Hence, the emphasis on using PageSpeed, HTTP2, above-the-fold CSS, async javascript, and on and on. https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/04/using-site-speed-in-web-search-ranking.html

Comment: Like @DisgruntledGoat said, this is a smaller factor for SEO. That said, it can make a bigger difference with regards to usability, and that in turn can lead to better metrics (recommendations, conversions, etc), so it's not something I'd ignore completely.

Comment: @JohnMueller Exactly what I'm saying.

Comment: Since this is about speed, you must be carefull that the function minimizing your html doesn't take too much time, otherwise it could actually get slower!

Answer (score 1):

In addition,

Minifying a resource, be it a CSS, JavaScript, or HTML file—is simply the process of removing spaces, comments, tabs, and other unnecessary code in the file.

There are many tools available for minification.

- Use Google’s Closure Compiler for JavaScript, YUI Compressor for CSS,
  and an HTML minifier for HTML. Again, it’s easiest to simply download
  the minified versions of the files PageSpeed Insights provides.
- If you’re running any CMS, you can take advantage of the
  minification by many plugins.

Google watches code. Not spaces between it.